# The significance of $\pi=\frac{\ln(-1)}i$

Tags: complex-numbers, pi

This is one way of defining $\pi$ but what does this definition tell us? This is undefined but $\pi$ isn't undefined.
$$e^{i\pi}+1=0$$
$$\pi=\frac{\ln(-1)}i$$

Comment: Not an answer, but be careful of taking natural logs of negative numbers. One must choose a branch cut and it isn't always well defined without that choice; see here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_logarithm

Comment: It says more about complex numbers than it does about $\pi$: the point is that multiplication by $e^i$ is counterclockwise rotation in the complex plane by one radian. This sounds mysterious (what does $e$ have to do with any of this?) but you can see it approximately by looking at multiplication by $(1+i/n)^n$ for large $n$. I seem to recall a nice visual on Wikipedia showing this, though I don't recall what article it was.

Comment: @Ian what does approximating using the multiplication of $(1+\frac{i}{n})^n$ mean?

Comment: @MohammadAreebSiddiqui It might be clearer if I am a bit more direct. We have $\lim_{n \to \infty} (1+\pi i/n)^n = e^{\pi i}$, which we want to show is $-1$. Multiplication by $1+ \pi i/n$ can be understood geometrically, it is the action of the matrix $\begin{bmatrix} 1 & -\pi/n \\ \pi /n & 1 \end{bmatrix}$. So multiplication by $(1+i/n)^n$ is multiplication by this matrix $n$ times. This matrix is just $(1+(\pi/n)^2)^{1/2}$ times a rotation by $\arcsin(\pi/n)$ radians.

Comment: @MohammadAreebSiddiqui So the problem reduces to showing that $(1+(\pi/n)^2)^{n/2} \to 1$ and $n \arcsin(\pi/n) \to \pi$ as $n \to \infty$, both of which are fairly routine calculations and have some geometric significance. (Typo in my previous comment: in the second-to-last sentence it should be $(1+\pi i/n)^n$ but I don't want to re-type the whole comment.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\ln(-1)$ isn't undefined, contrary to what is commonly taught in precalculus.

If we allow complex numbers $z = x+iy$ as input, then we can define the so-called principal value of the complex logarithm, denoted $\operatorname{Log}(z)$, as $$\operatorname{Log}(z) = \ln |z| + i\theta.$$  Here, $|z| = \sqrt{x^2+y^2}$ is the modulus of $z$, and $\theta \in (-\pi, \pi]$ is called the argument of $z$, which is, very loosely speaking, the angle that $z$ makes with the positive $x$-axis.  Note that we can define the complex logarithm slightly differently so that we don't have the principal value, but then we get into the concept of branch cuts and I think that is beyond the scope of necessary discussion here.

If we interpret $-1$ as the complex number $-1 + 0i$, then we have $$\operatorname{Log}(-1+0i) = \ln\left(\sqrt{(-1)^2 + 0^2}\right) + i\pi = \ln|1| + i\pi = i\pi.$$

This is how we can have $\ln(-1) = i\pi$, and therefore $\pi = \dfrac{\ln(-1)}{i}$.

In case it's not clear, the reason that $\theta = \pi$ for $-1 + 0i$ is because when we plot $-1+0i$ in the $xy$-plane, we plot it at the point $(-1,0)$, a full $\pi$ radians away from the positive $x$-axis.  And since $-\pi < \theta \le \pi$, then we take $\theta = \pi$ (and not, say, $-\pi$, or $3\pi$, etc.).

Regarding its significance.. Apart from being interesting and perhaps surprising at first, this isn't really a significant fact regarding $\pi$ in the sense that it has wide applications or gives us insight into anything regarding the digits of $\pi$.  Not as far as I know, anyway.

Comment: Excellent explanation! I totally understand how $\pi$ equals to that. And so this definition of $\pi$ is completely useless then?

Comment: @MohammadAreebSiddiqui, I'd be hesitant to say completely useless as the fact that I don't know any practical applications doesn't mean there aren't any.  But knowing what I do know, I'd be surprised if there were any.  I don't really think that $e^{i\pi} + 1 = 0$, or any of its related forms, are actually used as a *definition* of $\pi$.  Using this as a definition of $\pi$ when introducing $\pi$ is probably a horrible idea.  Otherwise it could be worth mentioning purely out of interest rather than practicality.

Comment: Ohhh got it...!

Answer (score 0):

Not a bad formula but unfortunately it uses a transcendental function to define $\pi$, which is not that useful.  It is perhaps more useful to provide a formula for $\pi$ that only uses roots; see [this article](https://arxiv.org/abs/1703.00425) (section 3.4).

Answer (score 0):

One way to view Euler's identity as saying that multiplication by $e^{i\theta}$ for real $\theta$ corresponds to counterclockwise rotation in the complex plane by $\theta$ radians. We can see this in the following manner. Let us take as given that $\lim_{n \to \infty} (1+i \theta/n)^n = e^{i \theta}$ (either by defining things this way or proving that whatever definition we use has this property).

Notice that multiplication by $1+i\theta/n$, just from the definition of complex multiplication, is the same as multiplication by the matrix $R(\theta/n)$ where $R(x)$ is defined as

$$\begin{bmatrix} 1 & -x \\ x & 1 \end{bmatrix}.$$

So multiplication by $(1+i\theta/n)^n$ is multiplication by $R(\theta/n)^n$.

Suppose now $\theta/n \in [-1,1]$ (always true for large enough $n$). From geometry, we know that $R(\theta/n)$ represents a rotation by $\arcsin(\theta/n)$ radians and a dilation by $(1+(\theta/n)^2)^{1/2}$. Thus the problem reduces to showing that $\lim_{n \to \infty} (1+(\theta/n)^2)^{1/2} = 1$ and $\lim_{n \to \infty} n \arcsin(\theta/n) = \theta$. These two calculations are routine and also have relatively simple geometric meaning.

Comment: A simple way of looking at this is that the length of arc of the unit circle from $1$ to $-1$ is $\pi$.